# unix pipe is streaming?

Tags: unix, stream, pipe, gzip

`zcat big.txt.gz  |  split  -l 1000000  - prefix`

where `big.txt.gz` is 150 GB, say it has ~1 billion lines.

**In this case, does the unix pipe "stream" the data into split, or is the  `zcat` operation completed, and then `split` is performed afterwards?**

It was not clear to me from [other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177740/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-pipes-and-streams) [pages](https://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe) if the above command would crash because it couldn't hold all of the gunzipped data in the pipe buffer before executing split, or if the gunzipped data would be "streamed" into `split`.

In general, the streaming behavior of unix `pipe` is unclear - when does pipe wait until all previous operations are finished before feeding input into the next commands stdin?

For example, if I were to link several more commands, would it crash due to lack of memory? e.g.

`zcat big.txt.gz | tr 'a' 'b' | sed 's/foo/bar/g' | grep 'hello'`

Comment: For this case, you are doing it right. You shouldn't have any trouble feeding a growing chain of piped "follow-on" commands. The pipe will block the producing process until consuming process signals "send me some more". Old MS-Windows pipes were not as flexible, (in my experience, it was easy to overwhelm with too much data, because it would work as you describe, really running 1 process at a time, creating a tmp file, and then connecting the next process to the 1st tmp file,and creating a 2nd tmp file, etc., etc. ) .Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

> A pipe has a limited capacity. [...] Applications should not rely on a particular capacity: an application should be designed so that a reading process consumes data as soon as it is available, so that a writing process does not remain blocked.

I'm not sure why there's any doubt here: the processes are running simultaneously, and the upstream process is writing *while* the downstream process is reading. Or at least that's the ideal specifically requested by this man page.

Now, it's possible that a given command may try to suck in all of its input before doing anything, and that too large an input may crash *that command*. But that's very different from the pipe buffer getting overfilled.

Comment: I am not aware of any clear-cut label or definition designating certain commands as compatible with immediate downstream processing, and others not.  For instance, how to be sure that `split` can consume data on the fly?  For another example, `sort` will surely not work in this manner, since it requires all of the data in order to sort it and pass it on.  Thus, there is no straightforward clear definition (for each utility)  of compatibility with "consuming data as soon as it is available".

Comment: This is correct and is more or less what I was trying to convey. But the answer to your question ("does the unix pipe 'stream' the data into `split`, or is the `zcat` operation completed and the `split` is performed") is unambiguously that the data is streamed (or more specifically I should say it is made available to the consuming process, which is already running). What the consuming process does with it is implementation-specific, and not really relevant to your question as asked.